# Parseval Theorem for a finite-valued function to the p-th power

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

According to Parseval Theorem (or Plancherel theorem), we have the following property. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two $L^2$ functions, and $P$ denotes the Plancherel transform,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \overline{g(x)} d x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\mathcal{P} f)(\xi) \overline{(\mathcal{P} g)(\xi)} d \xi,
$$
where 
$$
(\mathcal{P} f)(\xi)=\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} d x.
$$

My question is how it will be if we add more function into the integral? Assume all function are finite-valued and real.
For example:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|  d x=?
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) h(x) d x=?
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) h(x) i(x) d x=?
$$

In my current work, I use Parseval Theorem to exchange the inner product of "two" function between spatial domain and spectral domain, but I cannot deal the other cases.

Comment: It follows from the Fourier inversion theorem that $F^4 = Id$ so the **Fourier transform** $F$ is an unitary linear operator $L^2 \to L^2$ which means $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle Ff,Fg\rangle$ and $\|f\|^2 = \|Ff\|^2$ for all $f,g \in L^2$. It is the Hilbert space equivalent of orthonormal matrices. Of course you can't add "more functions".

Comment: Btw the formula you give for $\hat f$ is not correct unless $f\in L^2\cap L^1$; if you assume just $f\in L^2$ the integral need not exist.